# custom overlay (circle)

Tags: android, iphone, overlay, android-mapview

i was trying to show an overlay with circle shape 
in a region of 5000 by 5000
i defined the circle in the following way in viewDidLoad

```
MKCircle* circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coordinate radius:500];
[mapView addOverlay:circle];
```

and for the overlay view i gave the following code

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay {
 MKCircleView* circleView = [[[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay] autorelease];
 circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
 circleView.lineWidth = 2.0;
 //Uncomment below to fill in the circle
 circleView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
 return circleView;
}
```

but when i run this,only the map gets loaded,what is the error??

Comment: How are you setting the circle's center coordinate?

Comment: there is a coordinate variable of CLCoordinate2D type and i have assigned them like coordinate.latitude=12.3333 etc

Comment: Have you set the map view's delegate property?  Do you have other mapview delegate methods such as viewForAnnotation that execute fine?  Have you put an NSLog at the start of viewForOverlay to verify that it is executing?

Comment: thank you! that was the prblem,the maps delegate property was not set